# updating files through ftp on a provisioned/testing IP

Tags: php, ftp, sftp

I am moving my files from one server to another. Our new hosting company has given us provisional IPs for each domain/sub-domain (which I have modified my hosts file with + dumped dns). Additionally, they have provided username/passwords for these "fake" IPs for ftp/ssh. Although, when I try to connect to these servers, via IP, I get connection errors, ranging from "host not found" to "username/password incorrect". I have tried though WinSCP, FileZilla, and Dreamweaver. Is there something that I am missing? I'm to 'thick' to ask my hosting company (call it ego) what's wrong.

Question: If I'm given a provisional IP/username/password for a domain, is there some other requirement in order to connect to a domain in order to modify files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.. heres your options.

1. Firewalls in your company/house are blocking sftp (port 22)
2. They meant FTP not sftp
3. can you ping the IP (dependant on firewall too)

For the times you've had username/password rejections what were you using, as that at least made contact, or the error was misleading..

Comment: Testing your options:

1, 22 - no, 21 - no
2, ftp - no, sftp - no
3, ping - 4 requests; all 32 bytes; all < 100ms;  all 48 ttl

still stumped. I'll have to look into it further.

Thanks for the input... I may just have to knuckle up and ask them (sad face emoticon)

Answer (score 0):

Answer: The company provisioning my IPs did not add my IP to their firewall, so I wasn't allowed access.